# Edit App-V archive file

Tags: c#, powershell, zip, virtualization, appv

I'm trying to replace a file in a .appv archive file.

I know you can just rename the file to .zip extract and replace the file.
But when I zip it again and rename it back to .appv the file size is different and i get the following error when opening.

[image]

Im trying to change the AppxManifest.xml file or a setting within that without having to open via the UI(cmd, c# or powershell).

Thanks

Comment: When you say archive file, do you mean the .appv file?

Answer (score 0):

Open up your sequencer and choose "Modify"
[image]

"Update"[image]

Then I am skipping the steps where you upload your .appv file and installer (if you don't need the files from installer, you can always ignore it)

"Continue to modify"
[image]

Close the last page and it will automatically jumps to this page
[image]

Now, you can open up your package, expand the folder and add files if you want
[image]

Comment: I want to do it without opening the GUI as i have quite a few to change and want to run it as a script or a batch or even write a small program in c# c++ etc. I want to just tick VFS which is just setting a element to true in the xml file..

Comment: I am not sure if that's possible. But you might encounter some trouble because the VFS folder may require some elevated rights for you to write

Answer (score 0):

You cannot zip a package back and expect to work, this is **not supported by Microsoft**.

Starting with [App-V 5.1](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt346500(v=vs.85).aspx) the Sequencer from Microsoft can export and import the manifest file from the package, so you can modify it, but from what I know you cannot script this, it must be done from the GUI. The [list of powershell cmdlets for the sequencer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713419(v=vs.85).aspx) is quite short.

Also, [Advanced Installer can also create and edit App-V packages](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCB7hKA3ddE) much easily and faster than the sequencer, but again only from the GUI.

You can also try a free tool, called TweakApp-V, [here's an example](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f8fcaa7b-fd52-41c4-b252-94f175397076/setting-packageid-attribute-when-sequencing-in-unattended-mode?forum=mdopappv) of you can use it. It has predefined commands to [add/delete files and registry](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/appv-automation.html).

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use one of the application packaging tools that supports editing of App-V package. Apart from Advanced Installer that has been already mentioned, take a look at AdminStudio and PACE Suite - both support editing App-V. There may be even more than those two I know.